# Selenium: how to remove selected attribute

Tags: java, selenium

I have this `WebElement`:

```
<select id="month">
<option value="empty">Select</option>
<option value="1">Jan</option>
<option value="2">Feb</option>
<option value="3">Mar</option>
<option value="4">Apr</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">Jun</option>
<option selected="" value="7">Jul</option>
<option value="8">Aug</option>
<option value="9">Sep</option>
<option value="10">Oct</option>
<option value="11">Nov</option>
<option value="12">Dec</option>
</select>
```

And I want to remove the selected `attribute` from `Jul` and put this attribute under different `Month`.
This is what I have tried to remove the `Attribute`:

```
(JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('selected', '')", myElement)
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove the 'selected' attribute using Selenium? You can do it by Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

In general if you want to remove an attribute use the JavaScript `removeAttribute` method rather than trying to use `setAttribute`. In this case, though, you are working with a `select` and want to select a different element. Just use the built in Select class in selenium like this:

```
Select select = new Select(myElement);
select.selectByVisibleText("Aug");
```

I created an HTML file with the following contents and then tested it on that.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <select id="month">
            <option value="empty">Select</option>
            <option value="1">Jan</option>
            <option value="2">Feb</option>
            <option value="3">Mar</option>
            <option value="4">Apr</option>
            <option value="5">May</option>
            <option value="6">Jun</option>
            <option selected="" value="7">Jul</option>
            <option value="8">Aug</option>
            <option value="9">Sep</option>
            <option value="10">Oct</option>
            <option value="11">Nov</option>
            <option value="12">Dec</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then ran the following code:

```
@Test
public void testFoo() throws Exception {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage()
          .window()
          .maximize();
    driver.get("file:///blah/blah/blah/index.html");
    Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("month")));
    select.selectByVisibleText("Dec");
    Thread.sleep(10_000);
}
```

The page ended successfully with "Dec" selected.

Comment: I am familiar with this Select but from some reason this not working at all, i try selectedByValue, ByText... thats why i want to use JavaScript

Comment: I had the wrong method call (e.g. `selectByValue` instead of `selectByVisibleText`)...edited it along with adding the test I did where it worked successfully.

Comment: this is odd cause this is not selected anything, i try byValue, ByVisibleText and nothing

Comment: @davidhol It would be better if you can share the code snippet of what you have tried for selecting dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

To deselect an option you can use `deselectBy` methods

```
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("month"));
Select select = new Select(dropdown);
select.deselectByVisibleText("Aug");
// or
select.deselectByValue("7");
// or
select.deselectByIndex(8);
// or
select.deselectAll();
```

And to select another month

```
select.selectByVisibleText("Feb")
// or
select.selectByValue("2");
```

See [Select class](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select)